# simulating an eclipse like package explorer

Tags: java, swing

I'm a novice developer in Java Swing. I have a scenario:

I have an initial screen which takes a java project as input (uses filechooser). Now my next step is this, i want to display the heirarchy in a **JTree** (Packages,classes,methdos) as shown in eclipse by parsing the 'src' folder.

But the problem i'm getting is every folder is in the package structure is being displayed as a new child node (instead of the entire package name as a single node).

Kindly give me some idea regarding this. I'm entirely new to GUI in java. I googled about this but didnt found any solution

Comment: Each directory that has no files should put append to the previous to form a single node...

Comment: do you have some code or screenshots you could add to your question?